# How to create specific Viterbi Algorithm in Python for Homework?

Tags: python, statistics, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

So Basically for this homework, we're trying to use the Viterbi Algorithm to solve a hidden Markov model, I tried to base mine on others I found online but upon getting a hint from the teacher I'm overthinking it. I'm really good at the mathematical part and understanding how to do the problem on paper I just am horrible at translating it into python.

Below is the code I have so far that he helped me with his hints, I'm not sure what the next step is.

```
    import numpy as np

    def viterbi(obs):
        tmatr = np.array([[numpy.log2(0.7), 
                numpy.log2(0.2),numpy.log2(0.1)], 
                [numpy.log2(0.2), numpy.log2(0.5), numpy.log2(0.3)],[ 
                numpy.log2(0.1), 
                numpy.log2(0.3), numpy.log2(0.6)])
        omatr = np.array([[ numpy.log2(0.8), numpy.log2(0.2), 
                numpy.log2(0.0)],[ numpy.log2(0.2), numpy.log2(0.7), 
                numpy.log2(0.1)], 
                [numpy.log2(0.2), numpy.log2(0.5), numpy.log2(0.3)])

        pathdict={
        0: numpy.log2(.7),
        1: numpy.log2(.2),
        2: numpy.log2(.1),
        }

        probdict={
        0: (numpy.log2(.7)+ omatr[0,obs_seq[0]]),
        1: (numpy.log2(.2)+ omatr[1,obs_seq[0]]),
        2: (numpy.log2(.1)+ omatr[2,obs_seq[0]]),
        }

        templist=[]

        for t in range(1, 63):
             for i in range(0,2):
                 for k in range(0,2):
                    templist.append(pathdict[k,i]+
```

Comment: can you give a short explanation about what the next step you can not achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use the nested for loops to move from the initial probabilities above templist in order to basically update the HMM 63 times

Comment: Your initial transition matrix is invalid. The rows must all sum to 1. There is no need for all these `log2`, remove them and the matrix will be valid. What's your rationale behind using `log2` everywhere?

Comment: The transition matrix rows do add to one? and the log2s are because he told us when you go past like 10 iterations of this, the numbers get so close to 0 the computer will just make them 0, so you set them as logs so it keeps it a real number.